# Ray of Flame's damage progression

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells

Since the Ray deals 1d6 damage per 2 caster levels, what would be the damage if your caster level is lover than 2?
1/2, then round down. Ta-daa... 0, so 0d6 damage?

I'm pretty sure from common sense, it would be 1d6. So 1d6 on caster levels 1,2,3; 2d6 on caster levels 4 and 5; 3d6 on caster levels 6 and 7; and so on. But it would be nice to have  rule to prove this.

Comment: Where (book, page#) can we find the description of this spell?

Comment: Spell Compendium, p. 167

Comment: [Ray of Flame](http://therafimrpg.wikidot.com/ray-of-flame) from an online fan site, the wording of which seems to match the Spell Compendium.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, that spell deals no damage if you're a 1st level caster. You still get to kindle your target and deal him the continuous fire damage, though.

Comment: Odd result, but looks like it's the correct one. Note that some spells (Example: Divine Favor) that use this wording specify a minimum. This one doesn't.

Comment: That's quite reasonable, though seems kind of illogical from the point of common sense. Can someone ignite something with no fire damage at all?

Comment: @annoyingimp This is a case of RAW (Rules as Written) compared to RAI (Rules as Intended). I doubt they really intended a 0d6 fire spell at level 1, but they apparently managed to write one.

Comment: Of course, it's impossible to tell what RAI was, unless we ask to the authors, which leaves us with RAW and houserules.

Comment: @annoyingimp Yes, it is nonsensical and illogical. The RAW very often is.

Answer (score -1):

You are misunderstanding how 'x per 2 levels' works I think.

> A level 1 caster deals 1d6 damage.
>
> A level 2 caster also deals 1d6 damage.
>
> A level 3 caster deals 2d6 damage.
> etc. up to limit.

So a different way to read this would be "for every two caster levels, the spell deals d6 damage".

Comment: I think, it works like that when description specialy states: X spell deals 1d6 damage + another 1d6 per two caster levels, and the like. Like Orb of Acid, Lesser, exept that dice type is d8 there.

Comment: The exact wording is "If your attack is successful, the ray deals 1d6 points of fire damage per two caster levels (maximum 5d6)." This is different from Orb of Acid which states it deals extra damage for every two levels beyond the first.

Comment: And that's exactly what i mean. Your answer is legal for orb of asid, but not for ray of flame, as i understand it.

Comment: I edited the answer to try and make the wording even more clear, but in short, the difference is in the 'beyond the first'. Level 1&2 = 1 dice for fire, level 3 = 2, etc. Orb is 1&2&3 = 1 dice, because the first level is ignored.

Comment: Usually they say something like "for every level beyond first" to clarify this, or the spell is high enough level that it doesn't run into problems. As a DM I'd probably treat it the way you describe, but that's DM fiat to fix a rather poorly worded spell.

Answer (score -1):

If the dm deems the spell to powerful for a 1st level caster at 1d6 it would stand to reason he could half the dice at 1st so it would deal 1d3.

Comment: So this question has been downvoted; I didn’t, but I can see why. This site is a little different from discussion forums you might be used to; I suggest checking out the [Tour]. In particular, each answer really needs to b ea complete and backed-up answer to the question; just tossing an idea in is not sufficient for an answer here. The question asks for a “rule to prove this [damage progression],” and you don’t provide one, thus downvote. Again, the [Tour] should help explain how and why things work here, and give advice for how to write a good answer.